# regroup formset

Tags: django

Say I have a formset that I'm passing to a template. Each form has a `category` field that I'd like to sort the formset by. This is the code that I have so far:

```
...
{% regroup formset by category as category_formset %}
<ul>
    {% for category in category_formset %}
    <li>{{ category.grouper }}
        <ul>
            {% for form in category.list %}
            <li>{{ form.name.value }}</li>
            {% endfor %}
        </ul>
    </li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
...
```

The thing is that the output looks like:

- Category 1

  - ...
- Category 2

  - ...
- Category 2

  - ...
- Category 3

  - ...
- Category 3

  - ...
- Category 3

  - ...

That is, in the correct order, but not actually collated. I've already seen the "gotcha" [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#regroup) and tried adding `{% regroup|dictsort:"category" ... %}`, but that didn't help. Any ideas? Or is `{% regroup %}` not supported on formsets at all?

**Update:** I can get it to correctly collate the categories if I use `{% regroup formset by category.value ... %}`, but then it only displays integers (as `category` is a `ForeignKey` field). According to the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#regroup) it should be possible to use `{% regroup formset by get_category_display ... %}` to categorize on strings, but then `regroup` just returns `None`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So I did get it to work, in the end. The trick was to use `{% regroup formset by instance.category as category_list %}`, which will display plaintext category names and collate the entries correctly.

Comment: Thanks for the tip on this! Did you have to do anything special to get the 'ManagementForm data is missing or has been tampered with' error?

Comment: If anyone else gets stuck here understanding why "instance" works - it's because we're accessing the object instance from the form (docs allude to it here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/forms/modelforms/#overriding-clean-on-a-modelformset). So if you're like me and have a grouping by a foreign key to a foreign key, you can get access to your form instance like shown here, then access your model instance, then it's foreign key. E.g. `instance.category.category_group`